# C type won't be recognized properly

Tags: c, types

I have an error when I compile my C program.

I have this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SET__SIZE 10
#define SET__BOUND ((void*) NULL)

struct set {
  void *s[SET__SIZE];
  int cursor;
  int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*);
  void * (*copy)(const void*);
  void (*del)(void *);
};

int find(const void *s[], void *c, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
  int i = 0;
  while (s[i]!=SET__BOUND && cmp(s[i],c)<0)
    i++;
  return i;
}

int set__find(const struct set *se, void *c)
{
  return (se->cmp(se->s[find(se->s,c,se->cmp)],c)==0);
}
```

For some reason, gcc is raising a warning for the *find* call in *set__find* saying :

`note: expected ‘const void **’ but argument is of type ‘void * const*’`

I can't understand why he thinks the argument is a constant pointer (if I understood the error right)

Comment: `se->cmp` expects two `const void*`s but you provide two `void*`s. `se->s` points to `void*`, not to `const void*`, and `c` is also a `void*` and not a `const void*`.

Comment: FYI, while they’re fine in C, identifier with double underscores are reserved in C++. So if you want your code to be usable from C++, you should remove the double underscores.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried, the note goes away, when I change the code to

```
struct set {
  void *s[SET__SIZE];
  int cursor;
  int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*);
  void * (*copy)(const void*);
  void (*del)(void *);
};

int find(void * const s[], void *c, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
  int i = 0;
  while (s[i]!=SET__BOUND && cmp(s[i],c)<0)
    i++;
  return i;
}

int set__find(const struct set *se, void *c)
{
  return (se->cmp(se->s[find(se->s,c,se->cmp)],c)==0);
}
```

#### Explanation

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71242175/2976142)... No point of writting it again.

Answer (score 1):

> why he thinks the argument is a constant pointer

```
struct set {
   void *s[SET__SIZE];
```

The structure `set` *contains* the array `s`.

> const struct set *se

`se` *points* to a constant structure `set`. Because the structure is constant, the memory for the structure is constant. The elements of the array `s` can't be modified, they are in constant memory.

> ```
> find(se->s,
> ```

Arrays decay to the pointer to the first element. So imagine it's `TYPE s[SET__SIZE]`  where `TYPE` is a `void*`. `TYPE s[SET__SIZE]` decays to a pointer `TYPE *`. But, it's constant, so it's `const TYPE s[SET__SIZE]`. So it decays to a `const TYPE *`. You can't modify it, it's a constant array. `TYPE` is a `void*` - you can dereference the element and modify it then, but you can't modify the pointer value itself.

TL;DR you want `int find(void * const s[]` as in the other answer.